# Complicated transposing using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping someone can help me clear some data from a worksheet, then transpose a lot more.

I've got an exceptionally slow way of doing it at the moment with millions of lines of very bad code from just recording various steps but it crashes my computer every time so I'm hoping there's a quicker way.

I've attached a sample document for what the information looks like now and what I'd like it to look like afterwards.

I've used two sheets for clarity but ideally would like the action to happen over the top on the one sheet. This is not essential though.

There are three members in the sample but in reality there could be 100s.

I'm hoping to have the information in A18:B20 deleted, to follow in this way for each member, so deleting the rows relating to the below, then transposing the remaining info.

- Type
- Last Viewed
- Last notified

I can't seem to attach or post pics so here is a link - http://www.filedropper.com/sample_5

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is your data as well formed as your examples suggest?  All the "to be column headers" are the same; and always in the same order?  Are all the desired headers contiguous (no blank rows in the data) with the three rows to be deleted set off by blank rows?

Comment: Hi Ron. Thanks for coming back. The data is well formed, there may be some blank fields in the B columns, but the A column will always follow that pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions here requesting code indicate that the user has a basic knowledge of VBA coding, so I will provide you with a partial solution which you should be able to tailor to your specific needs.  You did provide good examples of your before and after requirements -- something that is critical and often lacking. They would have been better had they been unique, instead of identical, though.

The macro should reproduce what you have on your worksheets.  In particular it assumes the data is in columns A and B on sheet "Now" and will write the results to sheet "After".  But you should be able to figure out, perhaps with some research, how to change that.  Put this code into a regular module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TransposeMemberList()
    Dim sColHdrs() As String
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim lCols As Long
    Dim lMembers As Long
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range

'Set results Range First Cell
Set wsRes = Worksheets("After")
Set rDest = wsRes.Range("A1")

'get Source Data
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Now")
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'Assume colheaders all exist in first record
'Col Hdr 1 = Name
'How many columns?  Count to first blank in col A
With wsSrc.Cells.Columns(1)
    lCols = .Find(what:="", after:=[A1], LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                        searchdirection:=xlNext).Row - 1
End With

'How many Members?
'Count number of instances of first named column
lMembers = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsSrc.Cells.Columns(1), vSrc(2, 1))

'Populate Results Array
'First do column headers
ReDim vRes(1 To lMembers + 1, 1 To lCols)
vRes(1, 1) = "Name"
For I = 2 To lCols
    vRes(1, I) = vSrc(I, 1)
Next I

'Now do the columns for each memeber
'I = Member Rows in "Now"
'J = Member Row in "After"
'K = Member Column
I = 1
For J = 1 To lMembers
    vRes(J + 1, 1) = vSrc(I, 1)
    For K = 2 To lCols
        I = I + 1
        vRes(J + 1, K) = vSrc(I, 2)
    Next K

    'set I to next member by checking for first column header
    Do Until vSrc(I, 1) = vSrc(2, 1)
        I = I + 1
        If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    I = I - 1
Next J


Set rDest = rDest.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
rDest.EntireColumn.Clear
rDest = vRes
rDest.EntireColumn.AutoFit


End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Ron, much appreciated. Thanks also for the advice, will make sure I follow for next time.